# Chrome alerts error but does not show where it is

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, error-handling

When i open a web page with Chrome browser it shows me an error box caused by a javascript code but i don't know how to locate the exact place in the source code which is causing the error.

the alert box says: "Cannot read property 'style' of undefined"

Any help?

Comment: have you checked the information in the console ( press ctrl+shift+j ) ?

Comment: You have to provide some more info.

Comment: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Comment: Press Ctrl + Shift + I to open the developer tool of chrome, and add some more information

Comment: When i open the developer tool it shows me the html structure

Comment: The element doesnot have any style information or may be an empty element.Can you paste the html ?

Comment: i found where it is. 10x for your help